# onItemClick if go to FirstFragment else go to SecondFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, onitemclick

I need help.I'm Developing an app.

This is my navigation Bar. 
I have three options menu (the colored ones).

1) FirstFragment
2) MapFragment
3) Third Fragment

[image: Image Here]

And this is my navigation drawer consist of "Establishment Type List".

When clicked it will open another fragment (named ListFragment) that consist of List of the Establishments.

[image: list]

Establishments will have to functions go to the FirstFragment or else to the MapFragment.

Scenario:

1) If i'm in the 
FirstFragment->click navigation drawer-> click ListFragment-> Bank

In this scenario when the user clicks the bank it will check if the user is in the FirstFragment then it will proceed to the FirstFragment. Else it will go to the MapFragment........Result it will go to the FirstFragment.

2) If i'm in the MapFragment->click navigation drawer-> click ListFragment-> Bank

It checks if the user is in the FirstFragment else it will go to The MapFragment...........Result it will go to the MapFragment.

**Problem**: So the problem of this is I don't know how to implement it in my codes...

Here the Code in my MainActivity:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        if (id == R.id.action_ar) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, new FirstFragment())
                    .commit();
            Toast.makeText(this, "First Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if (id == R.id.action_map) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, new MapFragment())
                    .commit();
            Toast.makeText(this, "MAP Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if (id == R.id.action_direction) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, new ThirdFragment())
                    .commit();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Third Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Your problem exists in the `FirstFragment`, so you need to show that code...

Comment: The problem is I don't know how. That's why I need help.

Comment: I am asking you to please [edit] your question with more code... Though, your question seems unclear. Try to create a [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

You can pass a variable "from_where_did_icome"(e.g) every time you go to a fragment or another one to check from where you get there. For do that use this example code:

```
//Passing data to fragment:

Bundle bun = new Bundle();
bun.putString("pathimage", path);
fragment_setting.setArguments(bun);
```

---

```
//Getting data in fragment:

Bundle b = getArguments();
String path = b.getString("pathimage");
```

Learn more in this two links:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

Comment: Why would you need an extra variable to tell you what fragment you're in? Why would you use underscrored variable names like it's php?

Comment: @Nick it's not where you are but from what fragment/Activity you did come from, with that info we can decide what he ask with a simple if or switch after. Also edited the answer too.